# How to click on Toolbar Item with selenium?

Tags: selenium, toolbar

Web page contain a button with some text for example "Test". This button actually is a toolbar element. `( class ="tbButton" id="id",text="Test")` and redirects to a certain table when press on it.
When try to use the following click methods

```
selenium.click("id");
   selenium.doubleClick("id");
   selenium.click("//*[text()='Test'and contains(@class, 'tbButton')] ");
```

the button does not react
Could enybody show an alternative methods that is able to resolve a problem

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what the problem is without knowing more about the actual contents of the page you are testing.  Is there an example of the toolbar online somewhere?

With modern interfaces, locating elements with Selenium is not always an exact science.  Here are a few suggestions:

- With modern interfaces you often find that the DOM is being manipulated, so it is possible that the identifier you are using is no longer valid by the time you get to your `click()`.  Use Firebug to check that you have the correct element.
- Often it helps to click on the parent of the element, such as a `div` or the parent table cell.  Again, use FireBug, to try some other elements near your toolbar button.  Alternatively, Firebug sometimes reveals that the element contains other elements.  You might have more luck changing the target to a contained element instead.
- Sometimes you have to play around with some of the alternative actions.  For instance, some controls respond to a `mouseDown()` followed by a `mouseUp()`, but not to a `click()`.  Again you can often get hints from looking at the source with Firebug.